# How can I send a value of an upload file to another page?

Tags: php

I want to select an upload file on *index.php*. The "upload" button leads to *check.php*. If the file already exists the button "overwrite" appears. The overwrite button leads to *overwrite.php*
There I want to get my value again and finally upload the file into my folder.

index.php

```
<form action="check.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <button type="submit" value="upload">Upload</button>
</form>
```

check.php

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    $target_file = 'files/'.basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "File already exist";                  
        echo "<form action='overwrite.php' method='post'>
       <input type='hidden' name='newfile' value='$upload'>
                <button type='submit'> Overwrite</button>
            </form>";
    } 
}
```

overwrite.php

```
    $upload = $_POST["newfile"];


    if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {

                $file = $_FILES['file'];
                $target_file = 'files/'.basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

                $filename = $target_file;

                move_uploaded_file($upload, $target_file);
                echo "The file is overwritten";

}
```

There must be some mistake because the file is not overwritten.

Comment: just use Ajax for this. You're overthinking this.

Comment: I am unfortunately not familiar with ajax

Comment: Here's a tute http://codular.com/javascript-ajax-file-upload-with-progress which checks if a file exists.

Comment: Hello, thank you, the tutorial is ok, but it is not giving an error message when the file already exists and also not giving the possibility to overwrite. So with the tutorial made I still have the same problems

Answer (score 0):

if it already checks if the file exists, and all of that is correct, you could try to delete the old image before you upload. You can do this by using PHP's unlink function.

```
unlink($target_file);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! I did as you said, and it is working that the file is deleted. But still the file is not beeing overwritten.

Comment: @Jarla well it wouldn't be overwritten, because the file doesn't exist anymore. So intead of overwriting the file, try to save it normally after deleting the old one.